# Что за функция common_vsscanf()?

Tags: c++, api, runtime

Ковыряя в дизассемблере код очередной программы я столкнулся с вызовом следующей функции:

```
int common_vsscanf<char>(unsigned __int64, char const * const, unsigned __int64, char const * const, struct __crt_locale_pointers * const, char * const);
```

Никакой документации или описания на неё в интернете я не нашёл. Всё, что удалось найти - это внутренняя функция библиотеки runtime, которая вызывается из всех разновидностей функции scanf(), тем не менее в исследуемой мною программе она вызывается напрямую. Если кто-то поведает, что за параметры она принимает, как работает и какое значение возвращает, буду очень признателен. Спасибо.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsscanf-vswscanf?view=msvc-150

Comment: Если даже точно напрямую (а не из какой-то функции ...scanf) - то это просто компилятор какой-то вызов встроил...

Comment: @Harry или разработчики используют недокументированные api, такое тоже случается...

Comment: Просто внутренняя функция из реализации библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670 Всё оказалось иначе - это не common_vsscanf(). IDA ошиблась в сигнатурах))

Answer (score 0):

В общем, моё дальнейшее ковыряние в функции common_vsscanf() показало, что это вовсе не функция common_vsscanf(), и она даже не библиотечная! Просто IDA за каким-то лешим её так ошибочно распознала. То-то я по началу себе мозг сломал, видя явное несоответствие передаваемых параметров и контекста означенной функции!
Так что сама функция common_vsscanf() в данный момент для меня интереса не представляет. Всем спасибо за внимание!))